# Collection.contains() -> get the item

Tags: java, collections, set

I have a

```
Set<Resource> res = new HashSet<>();
```

Resource overrides `equals()` and `hashcode()` based on resource path.

Now I want to register a new resource, (if not loaded yet, load it):

```
Resource loadResource(String path) {

    // prepare a resource
    Resource newRes = new Resource(path);

    if(res.contains(newRes)) {
        // return that one
    }

    // load it (expensive)
    newRes.load();

    res.add(newRes);

    return newRes;
}
```

Now the question - how to do the "return that one" part?
ANy nicer way than a for-loop and checking each Resource to match `equals()`?

Comment: You don't have any way to do it in a `Set` except that by iterating through its elements using iterator. You may want to change the structure to a `Map` maybe.

Comment: Either use a map from paths to resources, or use a map from resources to themselves.

Comment: @ZouZou: `newRes` is equal to the one in the set, but it doesn't contain the state the one in the set has.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes you're right, I didn't pay attention that equals and hashcode were only based on the resource path.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `HashMap` that also use overridden `equals()` and `hashcode()` method for comparing. use *path*(or any one based on your logic) as key and *Resource* as value.

use `Map#containsKey()` to check for existing Resource.